# Changed Projected Coordinate System back to original but, Shape_Area field is still off by about 55 SF

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, attribute-table, shape-area

I recieved some GIS parcel data a little over a year ago. This data is the basis for the majority of my work. About a week ago I noticed that the Projected Coordinate System had somehow been converted from NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2011_Feet into WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere. I am not sure when this conversion happened as I have not needed to measure any parcels for quite some time. I noticed the change when I went to compare some of our assessing records against the GIS data and they were VERY different from one another. I have projected the data back into NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2011_Feet and the Shape_Area is now very close to the original data (I kept a backup copy of the original data on a disc) but is still short from the original by about 55 SF for the parcel I checked.

Can you help me to get the Shape_Area of these parcels to match the original data?

*Note - a few parcels have been changed from the original data so I cannot simply reload it. Also the to project my data back to its original Projected Coordinate System i went into ArcToolbox -> Data Management tools -> Projections & Transformations -> Project. Lastly, I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2 and the file I'm working with a File Geodatabase Feature Class.*

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  In your attribute table.  Right click on the field header *(Shape_Area)* and select *Calculate Geometry...*.

You will see the screen below.  Make sure you set your units correctly and that the Coordinate System specified is the correct one.

Let it calculate and then compare to your original.

**Run in Edit in case you don't like the results**

[image: Calculate Geometry]